# How to write to a NTFS partitioned drive from a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, ntfs

Looking for a good (preferably free) driver or way to enable read and **write** access to an **NTFS** hard drive from **OS X** 10.9.

Comment: This problem has only been asked a million times, and any google search with relevant terms should return results.

Comment: I obviously did a search before posting the question. I was surprise to see that there was no good answers for a **free** and **reliable** way to write on NTFS from OS X.

(Still looking by the way.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write support [can be enabled](http://osxdaily.com/2013/10/02/enable-ntfs-write-support-mac-os-x/), but it's not recommended.  Instead, consider putting the drive in a Windows PC and accessing across the network using SMB.

Comment: Putting the drive on the network is a creative solution which I did not thought about. Unfortunately, I do not have a windows machine on my network.

Answer (score 0):

I have very good experiences with Paragon from my Hackintosh times. Too bad it isn't freeware. http://www.paragon-software.com/nl/home/ntfs-mac/

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can format your hard disk to ExFat as this will be read/write on both Mac & Windows.
You can do it from Disk utility - select your HD from the left side - Then select Erase from the right side.
Make sure that you don't have any necessary files on the HD before formatting it.

Comment: I would like to avoid having to reformat the disk.